# "Connection is not secure" error in some of the promotion pages

Tags: bug, ssl, promotions

The following promotion pages are with the "Connection is not secure" error.

https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/1
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/2
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/3
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/4
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/5
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/6
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/7
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/8
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/9
https://contests.stackoverflow.com/promos/11

The error description in detail:

> Connection is Not Secure
>
> Parts of this page are not secure (such as images).

Due to some of the image files are in those pages are in `http://`, that caused the issue.

Comment: Looks like all the profile images are loaded from `http://www.gravatar.com` instead of https.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming this error is no longer happening...?